# How to slide the complete div left after click if performed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a beginner to javascript & html5 & css3. 
I am trying to add a groupon.com like feature where the user types info and go to next div.
I need to get to it slide or animate.

Currently I have a ccs :

```
#firstquestion {
    width: 500px
    z-index:3
    display: block 
}

#secondquestion {
    left: 800px;
    display: block;
}

#secondquestion {
    left: 800px;
    display: block;
}
```

and my form :

```
<form>
    <div id="firstquestion">
        <input value="your name" />
        <button onclick=""> continue </button>
    </div>
    <div id="secondquestion">
        <input value="You favorite book" />
        <button> Continue </button>
    </div>
    <div id="thirdquestion">
        <input value="Your favorite food" />
        <button> Continue </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Any help appreciate !

Comment: Try taking a look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions. Also, if you've using HTML5, consider using `placeHolder` instead of `value` for those input boxes...I believe that's what you're looking for there.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely explore some jquery.  It's pretty simple way to execute animations on sections of HTML.  [Here is jquery](http://jquery.com/).

Check out:
[codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com)
They have a great linear learning track to take you from infant webdeveloper to at least better than beginner.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use jquery as your javascript library www.jquery.com and use the animate function  http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Check out this link for some ideas about using jquery animate http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-animation-tutorials/

This should get you a bit further along the road to what you need.

Comment: thanks for the help but I cannot use jquery library. This has to be done in pure html5 and css3. If required, i will use javascript.